# Unobtrusive jQuery Set Attributes Before Append - Is More Effecient Syntax Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

The basic process for this code is:

- `$.get` a [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) template
- `$.getJSON` some data from the API
- Then the code below to process on the client

```js
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    item.Date = internationalDateTime(item.Date );
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, item);
    var $html = $(html);
    $html.find('input[name=btnView]').attr('onclick', 'loadView(' + item.Id + ')');
    $('#list-container').append($html);
});
```

Is there a better way (read more succinct I guess) of doing this without the need for the `$html` variable?

Not wanting to obsess over "one liners" in my code but it just looks a bit wrong to me.

Comment: It can also be `$(html).find('input[name=btnView]').attr('onclick', 'loadView(' + item.Id + ')').end().appendTo('#list-container');` but it doesn't add readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before adding your html to the DOM, you can do this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#list-container input[name=btnView][itemId]", function(){
    loadView($(this).attr("itemId"));
});
```

then just add your html to the page like this, the only point here is to store the `item.Id`:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    item.Date = internationalDateTime(item.Date );
    $(Mustache.to_html(template, item)).appendTo('#list-container')
        .find("input[name=btnView]").attr("itemId", item.Id);

});
```

your problem this way is just to get access to `item.Id`.

Comment: The only problem I see with that is that you could already have input elements that match your selector and you are affecting them as well, rather than just the injected ones.  Probably not relevant, but should be mentioned.  Also, this doesn't pass the `item.Id` into the event handler.

Comment: @Archer: thanks for your feedback, I tried to consider your point, I updated my answer now, the selector is more specific using `itemId` attributes, and it has access to `item.Id`.

Comment: I like your use of `itemId` in the selector - nice idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can trim it down, but for readability I normally do the exact type of thing you've posted...

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    item.Date = internationalDateTime(item.Date );
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, item);
    $(html)
        .appendTo('#list-container')
        .find('input[name=btnView]')
        .on('click', function() {
            loadView(item.Id);
        });
});
```

You could also get rid of the `html` variable, if you really wanted to, but I think you can go too far with minimizing code.

`appendTo()` will return the html as a jQuery object so you can find the input elements specified, and then attach a click event handler, all in one hit.

Comment: Yes, this way it's good. I would also prefer `on` instead of `attr`. So +1 too.

Comment: It took a few iterations and edits on my part too, as I kept seeing better ways.  I only spotted the onclick attr at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

What's about with:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    item.Date = internationalDateTime(item.Date);
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, item);
    html.querySelector('input[name=btnView]').addEventListener('click', function() {
        loadView(item.Id);
    }, false);
    $('#list-container').append(html);
});
```